# Remove slash ("/") with encode with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri

I have to encode a part of my code to send by email and I need to decode it after this when the user click on my link. But the problem was the encode function put slash ("/") ex:

```
$email_info =  $this->encrypt->encode($email.':'.$token); 
///if I ECHO $email_info I got this --> BmJXYlIlBQxbOwRsUiYEYQcxUBRXbgA/VXZQOg40VW4GPVB9AmRUPgVnVT9QNQNsC3cFagI3Bz4DZgViXD8CMVRuVToOMVYwAjAHdQk4A3IGbldyUj4FJVsrBHBSJQR8BzpQbVcxAGNValBuDmdVfQY5UCUCflQ1BXJVdA%3D%3D
```

In my other page , I do this: `$key = $this->uri->segment(3);`

So I only get this part `BmJXYlIlBQxbOwRsUiYEYQcxUBRXbgA`  because of the / after the letter A
so my next part of my code wont work ( my decode function `$array_info = $this->encrypt->decode($key);` )

I try a lot of things like `urlencode()`, `rawencode()`, and I always got "/" on my url ,

How can I encode this "/" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a raw replace:

```
str_replace("/", "%2F", $email_info)
```

or do try

```
rawurlencode
```

Comment: and I imagine to decode this  I need to do $email_info = str_replace("%2F", "/", $email_info)

Comment: humm...that won't work , I think My site_url() function convert  %2f  to /  :(. but you're solution will work if I found how can I fix this

Comment: yep but when I do site_url(reset_pass/'.$string.)  all %2f  auto-convert  to  "/" , I send this link by email to the user ... so he have the / inside is mail :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
  $new_email_info = str_replace( "/", "", $email_info );
```

print $new_email_info.